# I have stopped captureSession but Scanner is yet working. How to resolve this bug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, barcode-scanner

```
func scan(){
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeITF14Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }
    var capLayer = self.previewLayer
    capLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
    capLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    capLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.bounds
    self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(capLayer!)
    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func failed() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    captureSession = nil
}
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject: AnyObject = metadataObjects.first as AnyObject? {
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        foundCode(readableObject.stringValue)
    }
    if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func foundCode(_ code: String) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    storeID = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: DefaultsKey.storeID.rawValue) as? Int)!
    scannedCode = ("\(code)")
    if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil
    }
    apiCall()
}
```

Structure of my app: I am triggering scan on click of a button after successful API Call. I have stopped capture session once the barcode is found but it is continuously scanning and sendung multiple api calls.

Suggest how to stop camera from scanning without being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I guess at some point it still stops and we had the same issue with it. The problem with it is that capture session uses a Queue, and when it manages to scan something, it still is able to scan several times, until your code actually stops it. This is why you receive several delegate callbacks.

You can have 2 options here:

1. make the delegate `nil` when you first receive the callback and set it back again when you want to start.(Though I am not sure it will work)
2. as we did... introduce a bool flag to filter unwanted callbacks in your delegate.

Comment: I have tried the first suggested approach by you, it didn't work. Need to check with Second approach. Hope it works well

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall try by putting your stop scan code on main  queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Your code here
});
```

This will force your scanner to come on the main queue and make your processing time less.